# Prevent second touch from taking effect

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, input

I am trying to make a drawing app where the user can draw with a single touch. If the user removes the touch, he/she won't be able to draw any more by touching again. So, by simply touching a first time and swiping around, the user needs to draw.

In the code I am using, the user is still able to touch and draw as many times as he/she wants. I want the user to be able to draw at the first touch only.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>,
                        withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    swiped    = false
    if let touch = touches.first {
    lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self.imageView)

    }
}




override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>,
                            withEvent event: UIEvent?){

    swiped = true;

    if let touch = touches.first {

        let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(imageView)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
        self.imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height))

        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),CGLineCap.Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0)

        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        lastPoint = currentPoint


    }


    }




override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>,
                   withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if(!swiped) {
        // This is a single touch, draw a point
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageView.frame.size)
        self.imageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height))
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGLineCap.Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0)

        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y)
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flag to allow touches

```
var allowTouches = true

func touchesBegan() {
    guard allowTouches else {
        Return
    }
    // Your logic
}

func touchesMoved() {
    guard allowTouches else {
        Return
    }
    // Your logic
}

func touchesEnded() {
    allowTouches = false
}
```